# OCRApiService.com SDK issue?

Tags: ios, web-services, ocr

I have a question regarding to the code that OCRApiService.com provides to devs.

This is the code they provide:

```
//author : Altaf A. M.
//Code Snippet to convert the captured/picker'd (sic) image via OCRApiService 
//Input parameter: UIImage
//output parameter: NSString
//updates possible(rather necessary): integrate it asynchronously

- (NSString *) upload:(UIImage *)myImage
{
    NSString *urlString = @"http://api.ocrapiservice.com/1.0/rest/ocr";
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    // file
    //    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage, 1.0);
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"image\"; filename=\".jpg\""] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@""] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // Text parameter1

    NSString *param1 = @"en";
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"language\""] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:param1] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@""] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // Another text parameter

    NSString *param2 = @"YOUR_API_KEY";
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"apikey\""] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:param2] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@""] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // close form

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // set request body

    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    //return and test

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnedString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];


    //  NSLog(@"received string = %@", returnString);

    //  UIAlertView *returnedText = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Returned Text" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", returnString] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    //  [returnedText show ];

    //  [returnedText release];

    return returnedString;

}
```

I put in my API Key but the problem is whenever I call this method, I get

```
received string = HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
The language parameter is missing
```

According to the docs, I have set the language correctly but I am not sure why it is still coming up with this error message...

Thanks!

Comment: I am also willing to offer a bounty to anyone that helps me to get this to work!!!

Comment: Also the returnedString variable is the place where is comes up with this error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the owner of ocrapiservice.com.

The api is working but there is a bug in the code snippet.
Could you please open an issue on https://github.com/smart-mobile-software/ocrapiservice/issues ?

We will correct it within the week.

Comment: Ok Thanks! Also it would be helpful to include a way to make it a asynchronous method. It would also be helpful to show a callback method that gets called when the image gets fully loaded!